# What's the official name for this metal glue clamp for internal wires?

Tags: identification, clamp

I'm tasked with making a few new pieces of eqipment based on an existing one. This piece uses a few clamps like below to hold wires (usually a few at a time) connecting individual components inside its case. The clamps are glued to the device's case on the inside. The wires they hold are pretty thin, up to about 3 mm in diameter (with insulation) so the clamps are too quite small, on the order of 15x7 mm <sub>(can't measure them now, I've already used up all that were in stock)</sub>.

**What's the official name for them that I can find and order them by?** I searched by keywords like "metal wire clamp glue" but only larger ones, for entire cables, come up. Asking around at a large local electronics market also quite surprisingly yielded no results.

[image]

Comment: A generic trerm that may be useful in searching is "wire management" or "cable management".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a adhesive-mount metal cable clip. Similar to Panduit [MACC25-AV-D](http://www.panduit.com/heiler/PartDrawings/GB0239HH%20A%20RV%2000B.pdf) (photo from [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00B5LPEJ0) but they are available from regular electronics distributors).

[image]

Comment: The one in the post has a "movable" clip, this one appears to have a fixed clip

Answer (score 0):

Sticky clamps or sticky pad clamps comes to mind.

So see https://www.pinterest.com/pin/826410600342624151/

All you need is a bit of effort in google “heat resistant sticky cable clamp”...

Comment: Likewise, only plastic ones for entire cables come up in search :\